# Creating Business Units in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is it possible to move the journey in Parent unit seamlessly into a sub business unit? We created a journey in our Parent Business Unit. As we further expand our use of Marketing Cloud, we plan on creating additional business units.

Comment: I don't think you can move/migrate a journey from one BU to another.. you have to create it ground up in the new business unit.. At least this is what I have been doing. Haven't figured out a way so far

Answer (score 2):

You can use the REST API to retrieve an existing Interaction using the [getInteractionById method](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionById.html), then using the payload from the response, use the [createInteraction method](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/postCreateInteraction.html) to create a new one.

However, the problem is that activities are specific to the Business Unit. For example, emails relate to a Triggered Send in the Business Unit, filters used in Decision Split Activities and Events relate to filters in the Business Unit, Update Contact Data Activities relate to Data Extensions in the Business Unit and so on.

So yes, you can copy an Interaction using the REST API, but you would need to re-configure the Interaction Event and its Activities after doing so.

Comment: Thank you Eliot. We have decided to leave the initial journey running on the parent unit for the time being and move it at a later time.